# Flutter APP Does Not initialize especially on Galaxy Note Devices

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a flutter app on the Google Playstore. After a few updates, it doesn't work on Galaxy note devices. I don't know which update I changed many things but it doesn't appear on Firebase Crashanalytics dashboard.

I tried changing many things in android manifest file, main function and proguard file but none of them worked. Can you help me?

Note: The app works on most devices

Note: I created an empty flutter project it has the same problem (not working).
So I think the problem is not about main.dart or my pubspec.yml file

List of problematic devices:

- Note 9 pro Android 12.5.2 miu
- Samsung Galaxy Note 10+ Android 10 API   29
- Redmi Note 8 Pro  Android version: Android 11 (SDK 30)
- Huawei nova 3i  Android version: Android 9 (SDK 28)
- Redmi Note 9 Pro  Android version: Android 10 (SDK 29)

**flutter run** output

```
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...              1,892ms
E/DartVM  ( 7044): version=2.14.4 (stable) (Wed Oct 13 11:11:32 2021 +0200) on "android_ia32"
E/DartVM  ( 7044): pid=7044, thread=7120, isolate_group=main(0xc51aa800), isolate=main(0xc5155000)
E/DartVM  ( 7044): isolate_instructions=c7d1c8a0, vm_instructions=c7d1c8a0
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7e58c3b fp 0xc9b21098 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x19d5c3b
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc80cec41 fp 0xc9b210b8 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1c4bc41
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7d1ca46 fp 0xc9b210e8 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1899a46
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7ef216d fp 0xc9b21128 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1a6f16d
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7d52956 fp 0xc9b21168 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x18cf956
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7d58786 fp 0xc9b21198 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x18d5786
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7d53f3f fp 0xc9b21278 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x18d0f3f
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7d54c1b fp 0xc9b21348 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x18d1c1b
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7d647f6 fp 0xc9b21408 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x18e17f6
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7d64d4d fp 0xc9b214d8 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x18e1d4d
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc80b5cde fp 0xc9b21558 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1c32cde
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc80b6047 fp 0xc9b215f8 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x1c33047
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc786f806 fp 0xc9b21668 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13ec806
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7870827 fp 0xc9b216a8 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13ed827
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc786ec47 fp 0xc9b216d8 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13ebc47
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc786cb73 fp 0xc9b21748 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13e9b73
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc786c40c fp 0xc9b218b8 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13e940c
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc786bd66 fp 0xc9b21a38 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13e8d66
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7875172 fp 0xc9b21ba8 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13f2172
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc787c57e fp 0xc9b21cd8 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13f957e
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc788d0c9 fp 0xc9b21de8 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x140a0c9
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc782f91c fp 0xc9b21e08 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13ac91c
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7832b40 fp 0xc9b21e98 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13afb40
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7832a51 fp 0xc9b21ec8 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13afa51
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7839d83 fp 0xc9b21ee8 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13b6d83
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7839db1 fp 0xc9b21f08 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13b6db1
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xf495a488 fp 0xc9b21f38 android::SimpleLooperCallback::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+0x28
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xf495b415 fp 0xc9b22088 android::Looper::pollInner(int)+0x415
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xf495af4f fp 0xc9b220c8 android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+0x3f
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xe991f781 fp 0xc9b22118 ALooper_pollOnce+0x61
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7839cc6 fp 0xc9b22148 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13b6cc6
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc78329ff fp 0xc9b22168 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13af9ff
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7832527 fp 0xc9b22188 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13af527
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xc7836bb0 fp 0xc9b221c8 /data/app/com.appname.appname-4A2P7uXx7lz5bXHq_0FB1A==/lib/x86/libflutter.so+0x13b3bb0
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xf4c1cb06 fp 0xc9b221e8 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so+0x11ab06
E/DartVM  ( 7044):   pc 0xf4bb1648 fp 0xc9b22218 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so+0xaf648
E/DartVM  ( 7044): -- End of DumpStackTrace
Lost connection to device.
```

**flutter doctor -v**  output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Linux Mint 20.2 5.4.0-90-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.5.3 at /home/pc/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18116933e7 (4 weeks ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
    • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
    • Dart version 2.14.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/pc/Android/Sdk/
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /home/pc/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/203.7678000/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /home/pc/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/203.7678000
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.62.0)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.28.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Samsung Galaxy Note 10 (mobile) • 192.168.57.105:5555 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

**flutter run --release --verbose** output:

```
[  +48 ms] executing: uname -m
[  +23 ms] Exit code 0 from: uname -m
[        ] x86_64
[   +6 ms] executing: [/home/pc/snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +3 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 18116933e77adc82f80866c928266a5b4f1ed645
[        ] executing: [/home/pc/snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git tag --points-at 18116933e77adc82f80866c928266a5b4f1ed645
[  +13 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at 18116933e77adc82f80866c928266a5b4f1ed645
[        ] 2.5.3
[  +10 ms] executing: [/home/pc/snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +3 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/home/pc/snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +2 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +73 ms] executing: [/home/pc/snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +3 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +42 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +74 ms] executing: /home/pc/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +24 ms] List of devices attached
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'PubDependencies' is not required, skipping update.
[  +31 ms] No supported devices connected.
[   +7 ms] "flutter run" took 160ms.
[  +15 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:461:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1232:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[ +194 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 192ms
[        ] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

Comment: I tried to run it with an empty main file still the same error so the problem is not on the main.dart I have tried this code https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab

Comment: I created an empty flutter project it has the same problem (not working). So I think the problem is not about main.dart or my pubspec.yml file

Comment: This topic was related but I couldn't find the solution
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74655

Comment: I had similar issue, any solution found?